# Adding an item to an existing object loaded via Import-Clixml with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I can't get my head around how to add an existing item to an object that (in this instance) has been loaded via `Import-CliXML`.

My XML file is a simple object that contains a table of role and assignee pairs. When the file doesn't exist, it works correctly. If the file contains an existing role it updates it successfully. However if the role being set does not exist in the file (and therefore should be added to it), I get this error:

> Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
>   At C:\Users\me\Set-TeamRole.ps1:33 char:9
>   $TeamRoles += $RoleObj

Here is my code:

```
function Set-TeamRole {
    Param(
        [string]$Role,
        [string]$Assignee,
        [string]$Path = 'TeamRoles.xml'
    )

    if (Test-Path $Path) {
        $TeamRoles = Import-Clixml $Path
        $ExistingRole = $TeamRoles | Where {$_.Role -eq $Role}
    } else {
        $TeamRoles = @()
    }

    if ($ExistingRole) {
        $ExistingRole.Assignee = $Assignee
    } else {
        $RoleObj = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject

        $NewRole = @{
            Role = $Role;
            Assignee = $Assignee;
        }

        Add-Member $NewRole -InputObject $RoleObj
        $TeamRoles += $RoleObj
    }

    $TeamRoles | Export-Clixml -Path $Path -Force
}
```

Comment: I would suspect that the improted file contained only a single item. Try `$TeamRoles = @(Import-Clixml $Path)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the input XML file contains only one object, the statement

```
$TeamRoles = Import-Clixml $Path
```

will not produce an array, and consequentially the statement

```
$TeamRoles += $RoleObj
```

will try to invoke an addition operation on that object instead of appending to an array (and fail if that object doesn't support such an operation).

You can force the imported data into an array by running `Import-Clixml` in an [array subexpression operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators):

```
$TeamRoles = @(Import-Clixml $Path)
```